# Speeding up OS X boot times on a year old MBP

Tags: macos, boot, macbook

I've had my MBP for a little over a year now.  It used to boot up lightenign quick, to the envy of my Windows friends.  Not so much anymore.

What can I do to speed up the boot time on my OS X 10.5 MBP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of any accumulated cruft you don't need, e.g.

- Startup Items (Accounts -> Login Items prefs)
- Background services such as web server, universal access, bluetooth etc.
- <strike>Dashboard widgets</strike>
- Extra preference panes

And:

- Make sure you have enough (at least 10%) free space on your HD
- Defrag

Comment: widgets don't load until you activate dashboard for the first time actually

Comment: Defrag? Don't bother. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1375

Comment: Defrag - do bother if any of the following conditions hold:
1) You're about to  bootcamp Windows;
2) Your drive is very full > 80%;
3) You work with large files;
4) You have system slowdown and have tried everything else.

Comment: You could also repair your drive with Disk Utility - any corruption will slow bootup.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reboot?  The only time I actually reboot my Mac laptops is after installing system updates.  The rest of the time, I just let them sleep.  This has worked well for years.  The only time that this isn't an option is if won't be plugged in for days, since it does use a minimal amount of power.

Comment: I'm already there...I only reboot once every several days (like when i am on the road and want to conserve battery.)

Comment: Full ACK, I also just reboot when a system update requires it.

Comment: @Stu - instead of rebooting, use hibernate. it is quicker, and your apps will already be launched for you.

Comment: That causes its own problems - you can see RAM fragmentation if you really leave the Mac on for a long time.
Rebooting usually speeds things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I always do some maintenance every month, which usually involves clearing a few caches etc.

I feel as though it makes things faster, so it may help you too.

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/onyx.html